# How To Fix NullReferenceException - everything works in game as I wanted tho

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have script for Hart counting, when enemy hit player, -1 life etc.

Everything work perfect, Value show on the screen, decreasing like it supposed to.

But in CONSOLE I'm getting this error:

**NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
HartCount.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/HartCount.cs:31)**

can this stay like that? as everything works etc. but it's kind of annoying to have this error.

```
public class HartCount : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int HartValue = 10;
    Text Hart;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Hart = GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Hart.text = "" + HartValue;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is 31? You only included 17 lines.

Comment: You have added the `HartCount` script to an object that doesn't have a `Text` component attached. You can search for `HartCount` in search field in the GameObject hierarchy view to find all GameObjects with this script attached, to find which object it is.

Comment: See: [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/3744182).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HartCount` script is attached to a GameObject that doesn't exist. Double check this, set a breakpoint after `Hart = GetComponent<Text>();` and make sure that value is populated with the component.
`